# OpenSSH: option named 46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy

Tags: windows-10, openssh

With the 2017 Fall Creators Update, Microsoft [added a version of OpenSSH](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/) to Windows 10, which got out of beta and is enabled by default in the recent April Update.

Today I tried to take it for a spin and saw that its usage page lists an option named `46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy`. usage: `ssh -46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy`.

Upon running the above command. PowerShell prints the following output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh -46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
```

This looks like a version number of sorts.

I have looked in the Microsoft Docs to find more information about `ssh` and this flag, but to no avail. A documentation page on [this website](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD) shows the option, but doesn't explain what it should do. To me, it looks like a combination of multiple options, but that doesn't explain why it outputs a version number.

**My questions are the following:**

1. Is it normal for `ssh` to have an option with such a peculiar name?
2. If yes, where does it originate from?
3. Is this the expected output for this command?

Is anyone able to provide some more insight on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see from the site you linked to they are separate options, not a single option. `-4` means one thing, `-6` another, etc. The reason they’re in one blob is because they don’t take any parameters and they can be combined, meaning `-4A` would be the same as `-4 -A`. This saves space on manual pages but is confusing unless you know about it.

After them are all the options that do take parameters, like `-B`.

The version number is shown because `-V` shows the version number and exits and is included there.

Comment: It could, but combining `-4` (IPv4 only) and `-6` (IPv6 only) doesn't make any sense

Comment: That’s why they aren’t combined. It’s just a list of possible options, not something you would use.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the combination of letters that are not listed on the following display of "menu of possible usage parameters" but have any potential behavior.

You see, as you just type `ssh` and these basic parameter examples appear:

```
~/ >  ssh

usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
       [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
       [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
       [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
       [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
       [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
       [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

You could realize that none of the letters in this string `46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy` is found among the following specific parameter examples.

Since the options can be combined,

```
~/ >  ssh -46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy

OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

is the same command as

```
~/ >  ssh -4 -6 -A -a -C -f -G -g -K -k -M -N -n -q -s -T -t -V -v -X -x -Y -y

OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

which is, in your case and my case, catchs the only available extra command `-V`, and the other parameters are ignored because they are **reserved but not designed to run by itself**. Therefore, it is the same command as

```
~/ >  ssh -V

OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

(also ignoring the lowercase `-v` option)

Well, according to my personal guess, ssh would not like to display this messy chunk in even messier way like

`usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy you_can_try_any_other_possible_parameters_like_these_which_are_not_listed]`